# Adding Java code to worklight adapter

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I need to call a Java function from the worklight ADAPTER. I have followed the "adding Java to worklight adapter" document, but my problem did not get solved. I was not able to call the function.

The structure of the Java code that I have is as follows:

```
server/java
com.worklight.custonmode           package name
loginfunction.java                     java 
login                              java method in class loginfunction
```

From the adapter, I am calling:

```
function loginmodules(username, passwd) {   
    return {
        result : com.worklight.custonmode.loginfunction.login()
    };
}
```

I am getting the error as:

> response [/apps/services/api/erLight/common/query] success: /*-secure-
>   {"responseID":"2","errors":["Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot call
>   property login in object [JavaPackage
>   com.worklight.custonmode.loginfunction]. It is not a function, it is
>   \"object\".
>   (C%3A%5CUsers%5CADMIN%5CworkspaceM11%5CMobileClient%5Cadapters%5CAdapter/Adapter-impl.js#103)"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/
>
> worklight.js (line 1112)
>
> Procedure invocation error. Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot call
>   property login in object [JavaPackage
>   com.worklight.custonmode.loginfunction]. It is not a function, it is
>   "object".
>   (C%3A%5CUsers%5CADMIN%5CworkspaceM11%5CMobileClient%5Cadapters%5CAdapter/Adapter-impl.js#103)

Comment: What is the "'adding Java to worklight adapter' document"? Do you have a link?

Comment: yes i have ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/Module_05_5_-_Using_Java_in_Adapters.pdf or http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#authentication   download module_05_5